# Skating off an edge with torque ambiguity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, oscillators

**Problem**
In this particular case of a dynamic skating motion combining translation and rotation, I consider the question of determining the appropriate torques and applying the correct rotational version of Newtons 2.nd law. To me this seems to involve some ambiguity which I would like to have resolved by someone capable. Therefore this question - and I am not a student!

**Setup**
We consider the motion of an idealized roller skate as it with constant speed v goes over the right hand edge of a table or shelf. Fig.1 shows the details of the skate and its run-up to the edge.

[image: Fig. 1 Idealized model of skate running on table]

**Fig. 1** *Idealized model of skate running on table*

Since no horizontal forces seemingly affects the skate the horizontal component of the velocity v should be constant during the motion, airborne or not.
(Is this assumption absolutely true?)

**Moments of Inertia**
In our calculations, the mass of the board is taken to be zero so the moment of inertia $I_A$ around either the front or back wheel center is given by the parallel axis theorem $I_A=2ML^2+I_C$.
Fig 2 below illustrates the two rotation situations.
[image: Fig.2 Illustrating the moments of inertia]
**Fig.2** *Illustrating the moments of inertia*

NOTE: The moments of inertia of each of the wheels themselves relative to their own rotation is taken to be zero so they can be thought of as point masses. This implies that we can set $I_{\mathcal{C} }= 2ML^{2}$and$\quad I_{\mathcal{A} }= 4ML^{2}$ and still obey the parallel axis theorem.

**Torque Configurations**
First of all, we should agree that for a solid, rigid body the angular velocity $\omega$ and its time derivative $\dot{\omega}$ is the same no matter which axis of rotation is chosen within the body.
Now torque generates rotation but the calculations can depend on how the forces are interpreted (internal/external/inherent) and the choice of torque center or pivot.
With this in mind several torque configurations can be devised.
The presumably most correct configuration is shown in Fig. 3.1 where $F$ is the reaction force of the table that pushes the rear wheel upwards and causes a rotation about C.
It can be argued that if $F$ is positive, i.e. not fully counteracted by the gravitational pull on the rear wheel, then the wheel center A must accelerate upwards and the wheel will lose contact with the table.
According to Newton 2, the gravitational forces are concentrated to act on C, so they do not directly induce a rotation about C. This leads to 1.1) $\dot{\omega}I_{\mathcal{C}}=KF$ .
On the other hand one could argue the the gravitational pull on C causes the skate to pivot about A. This leads to 1.2) $\dot{\omega}\boldsymbol{I}_{A}=2KM\mathbf{G}.$

[image: Fig. 3.1 Likely torque configuration]

**Fig. 3.1** *Likely torque configuration*

We now forget about the center of mass representing a concentration of all gravitational forces and consider the situation shown in Fig. 3.2

[image: Fig. 3.2 Is the front wheels momentum already included?]

**Fig. 3.2** *Is the front wheels momentum already included?*

Here we assume that the mass at A, which is supported by the table, can not by itself induce any rotation but that this is solely up to the reactionary force $F$ and the mass pull $MG$ on the airborne front wheel. This leads to 2.1) $\dot{\omega}I_C=KF+KMG$ when C is taken as
the pivot and 2.2) $\dot{\omega}I_{4}=2KMG$ when A is taken as the pivot. Notice that 1.2) and 2.2) are in agreement but 2.1) and 1.1) disagree. I suspect that this disagreement stems from the fact that $I_{\mathcal{C}}$ in 1.1) already includes the effect from the mass at B and thus is correct. Finally in Fig. 3.3 we consider all forces concentrated to act on C giving
3.1) $\dot{\omega}I_A=K(2MG-F)$ .Since the force $F$ is physically associated with the wheel center at A, it is probably wrong to let it participate in inducing a rotational momentum around
A, so I suspect that 2.2) is the correct expression. Incidentally, with this configuration the skates vertical downwards acceleration is determined by 3.2) $2M\ddot{y}=2MG-F$​​​.

[image: Fig 3.3 All attacking forces concentrated at C]

**Fig 3.3** *All attacking forces concentrated at C*

**Tentative solution**
Here we refer to Fig. 4 which is a repetition of a previous configuration but with some additional details included for calculation purposes.

[image: Fig. 4 Basis for equations of motion]

**Fig. 4** *Basis for equations of motion*

We use this configuration as the basis for determining the skates vertical downwards acceleration,which according to Newton 2 is

4. $\quad2M\ddot{y}=2MG-F$​​​

From $FL\cos\theta = \dot{\omega}I_C$​​​ we can eliminate the undetermined force $F$​​​ to obtain

5. $\quad\ddot{y}=G-\dot{\omega}\frac{I_{C}}{2M\cos\theta}$​​​

With $y=L\sin\theta$​​​ we then get the differential equation

6. $\quad L\frac{d^2\sin\theta}{dt^2}=G-\frac{d\omega}{dt}\frac{I_C}{2ML\cos\theta}$​​​

Using $\dot{\omega}=\frac{d\omega}{dt}=\omega\frac{d\omega}{d\theta}$​​​ this can be transformed  to give

7. $\quad\frac{d(\omega^2)}{d\theta}-\frac{4ML^2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{2ML^2\cos^2\theta+I_C}(\omega^2)=\frac{2GML\cos\theta}{2ML^2\cos^2\theta+I_C}$

which is a first order differential equation in $\omega^{2}$​​​and $\theta$​​​ with the solution

8. $\quad\omega^2=\frac{2GML}{I_{C}}\frac{\sin\theta}{1+k^{2}\cos^{2}\theta}$​ where $k^2=\frac{2ML^{2}}{I_{C}}$​​

This implies that $t$​​​ as a function of $\theta$​​​ is determined by the integral

9. ​$\quad\frac{2GML}{I_c}t=\int\frac{\sqrt{1+k^2\cos^2\theta}}
   {\sqrt{\sin\theta}}d\theta$​​​

which unfortunately can not be expressed with standard functions.

**Similarity with Pendulum**
Since previously, in connection with the torque configuration in Fig. 3.2, the equations 1.2) and 2.2) saying that $\dot{\omega}I_{A}=2KMG$ agree, we are tempted to explore this a bit further.
Again using $K=L\cos\theta$ we then have $\dot{\omega} I_A= 2MGL\cos \theta$ or $I_A d\omega^2 = 2MGL\cos\theta d\theta$. Integration of this then gives the exact equation for a simple pendulum with a large angle displacement $\theta$, mass 2M, length 2L and moment of inertia $I_{A}$ around its suspension

$
10)\quad\omega^2=\frac{4MGL}{I_A}\sin\theta 
$

which is somewhat similar to 8), but which one, if any, is the correct solution for this case?

Comment: During the period where one set of wheels is on the table and one is not, we are inducing a torque.  One would need to know the moment of inertia to model what happens.

Comment: This will probably be flagged as homework so I will just a give a couple of pointers. The horizonal motion f the COM will be constant as you say. The COM will also fall and accelerate downwards as if it was a point particle equal to the total mass of the skate board. On top of this there will be torque rotating the board so you will have to locate where the ends of the board are at any point in time, relative to the centre is, taking the rotation into account.

Comment: @KDP Please don't use comments to give partial answers to off-topic questions. If you think a question is on-topic and deserves a brief answer, then write a brief answer in the answer box. If you think a question is off-topic, please flag or vote appropriately. Answering off-topic questions — especially in comments, where our feedback mechanisms are less robust — encourages more off-topic questions.